# Why doesn't a C4H8 alkane exist?

Tags: organic-chemistry

This structure:

```
     H   H
     |   |
 H - C - C - H
     |   |
 H - C - C - H
     |   |
     H   H
```

Which would be $\ce{C4H8}$, like butene, but an alkane, because it's functional group is C - C.

Comment: Um....cyclobutane is a commercially available liquefied gas. Am I missing something here?

Comment: With the missing bond added, your structure is fine and part of a family known as [cycloalkanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloalkane).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclobutane

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does exist. The formula $\ce{C_{n}H_{2n+2}}$ is only applicable to straight chain alkanes. They can't have any degrees of unsaturation, which is defined as a multiple bond or a ring.